# How can I get a specific field of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I need a way to get a specific item(field) of a CSV. Say I have a CSV with 100 rows and 2 columns (comma seperated). First column emails, second column passwords. For example I want to get the password of the email in row 38. So I need only the item from 2nd column row 38...

Say I have a csv file:

```
aaaaa@aaa.com,bbbbb
ccccc@ccc.com,ddddd
```

How can I get only 'ddddd' for example?

I'm new to the language and tried some stuff with the csv module, but I don't get it...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Is your edit correct? First it seemed the OP wanted the last term of a line... Otherwise the question is difficult to understand: Do the OP want the last string after the last comma in the csv file?

Comment: @joaquin: All I changed was replacing `???` with `?`. And John's edit just added code formatting (the question's code already had two lines before) so I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: The file is email,password per row for example 1st column email, second column password. I want to get only the password of the 2nd row for example

Answer (score 33):

```
import csv
mycsv = csv.reader(open(myfilepath))
for row in mycsv:
   text = row[1]
```

Following the comments to the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249185/using-python-to-append-csv-files/4250021#4250021), a best, more robust code would be:

```
import csv
with open(myfilepath, 'rb') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in mycsv:
        text = row[1]
        ............
```

**Update:** If what the OP actually wants is the last string in the last row of the csv file, there are several aproaches that not necesarily needs csv. For example,

```
fulltxt = open(mifilepath, 'rb').read()
laststring = fulltxt.split(',')[-1]
```

This is not good for very big files because you load the complete text in memory but could be ok for small files. Note that `laststring` could include a newline character so strip it before use.

And finally if what the OP wants is the second string in line n (for n=2):

**Update 2:** This is now the same code than the one in the answer from J.F.Sebastian. (The credit is for him):

```
import csv
line_number = 2     
with open(myfilepath, 'rb') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    text = mycsv[line_number][1]
    ............
```

Comment: Note that `row[1]` is probably what you want, as indexing in Python is zero based. Also, you should always open CSV files in binary mode, as in `open(myfile, 'rb')` -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249185/using-python-to-append-csv-files/4250021#4250021).  Oh, and +1 for use of the CSV module (which, as Tyler pointed out, will handle quotes and whatnot properly).

Comment: @benhoyt: I suppose, I wrote row[2] before the re-edition of the question. before it was  `aaaaa@aaa.com,bbbbb ccccc@ccc.com,ddddd`

Comment: @benhoyt: thnks for the link. I updated the answer and took note

Comment: When I print row[1] I get all items of the 2nd column, but I only want one item, the 'ddddd'...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need a way to get a specific item(field) of a CSV. Say I have a CSV with 100 rows and 2 columns (comma seperated). First column emails, second column passwords. For example I want to get the password of the email in row 38. So I need only the item from 2nd column row 38...

Comment: Look the new answer. Try to be more clear in your question next time. You can edit yourself your question to clarify it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working fine now! And sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: Your code is unnecessary complicated. To extract a row with a given `line_number` you could `row = next(itertools.islice(csv.reader(f), line_number, line_number+1))` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757743/python-how-can-i-get-a-specific-field-of-a-csv-file/5758901#5758901

Comment: @J.F Sebastian: tnks I know, the code has evolved trying to fit the different explanations from the OP. Please, post yourself your answer (I will vote for it :-)) I already posted a new answer trying to generalize the problem of the OP (asking for codes at different lines)

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Print a field specified by row, column numbers from given csv file.

USAGE:
    %prog csv_filename row_number column_number
"""
import csv
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
row_number, column_number = [int(arg, 10)-1 for arg in sys.argv[2:])]

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
     rows = list(csv.reader(f))
     print rows[row_number][column_number]
```

#### Example

```
$ python print-csv-field.py input.csv 2 2
ddddd
```

Note: `list(csv.reader(f))` loads the whole file in memory. To avoid that you could use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
# ...
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
     row = next(itertools.islice(csv.reader(f), row_number, row_number+1))
     print row[column_number]
```

Comment: That still requires reading in all the lines until you get to where you want.  The question is how to ONLY read what you want.

Comment: @Confounded: lines in csv may have a different length. There is no way to get the exact `row_number` without reading the file (note: `islice` version does not store the whole file in memory). To be able to seek (jump in the file) to the exact row number, you need a fixed format (binary format essentially) where you can predict the position inside the file (or don't care about precision)

Comment: And what is such file format? I am dealing with data (all double-precision floating-point format) that has multiple dimensions (i.e. a hyper-cube) and I am looking for ways to store and be able to access sections of that data.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

There is an interesting point you need to catch about csv.reader() object. The csv.reader object is not `list` type, and not subscriptable.

This works:

```
for r in csv.reader(file_obj): # file not closed
    print r
```

This does not:

```
r = csv.reader(file_obj) 
print r[0]
```

So, you first have to convert to list type in order to make the above code work.

```
r = list( csv.reader(file_obj) )
print r[0]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import csv

def read_cell(x, y):
    with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        y_count = 0
        for n in reader:
            if y_count == y:
                cell = n[x]
                return cell
            y_count += 1

print (read_cell(4, 8))
```

This example prints cell 4, 8 in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Following may be be what you are looking for:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")

print(df["Password"][row_number])  

#where row_number is 38 maybe
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I got it!!!

```
import csv

def select_index(index):
    csv_file = open('oscar_age_female.csv', 'r')
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        l = line['Index']
        if l == index:
            print(line[' "Name"'])

select_index('11')
```

> > > "Bette Davis"

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv
inf = csv.reader(open('yourfile.csv','r'))
for row in inf:
  print row[1]
```