# How to read specific columns and Rows in Python?

Tags: python, csv

> Timestamp         SP  DP
>   20-03-2017 10:00:01 50  60.5
>   20-03-2017 10:10:00 60  70
>   20-03-2017 10:40:01 75  80
>   20-03-2017 11:05:00 44  65
>   20-03-2017 11:25:01 98  42
>   20-03-2017 11:50:01 12  99
>   20-03-2017 12:00:05 13  54
>   20-03-2017 12:05:01 78  78
>   20-03-2017 12:59:01 15  89
>   20-03-2017 13:00:00 46  99
>   20-03-2017 13:23:01 44  45
>   20-03-2017 13:45:08 80  39

```
import csv    

output = []

f = open( 'test.csv', 'r' ) #open the file in read universal mode
for line in f:
    cells = line.split( "," )
    output.append( ( cells[ 0 ], cells[ 1 ] ) ) #since we want the first, second column
print (output)
```

how to read specific columns and specific rows?

Desired Output:

i want only first column and 2 rows;

> Timestamp         SP
>   20-03-2017 10:00:01 50
>   20-03-2017 10:10:00 60

How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a specific field of a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757743/how-can-i-get-a-specific-field-of-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your `csv` module, and either count your rows (using the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) or use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to limit how much is read:

```
import csv

output = []

with open( 'test.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for counter, row in enumerate(reader):
        if counter > 2:
            # read only the header and first two rows
            break
        output.append(row[:2])
```

or using `islice()`:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open( 'test.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    output = list(islice((row[:2] for row in reader), 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You to use pandas to read it.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("filepath", index_col = 0)
```

Then you can call first column and 2 rows by

```
df.SP.head(2)
```

or

```
df.ix[:1, 0:2] # first row and column first two column
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use index slicing. Just read csv from the source.

```
from pandas import *

df = read_csv("Name of csv file.")

df2 = df.ix[:1, 0:2]

print df2
```

Try it.

Comment: @TB.M, check this out.