# How to split tsv file into smaller tsv file based on row values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tsv file `in.txt` which I would like to split into a smaller tsv file called `out.txt`.

I would like to import only the rows of `in.txt` which contain a string value `My String Value` in column 6 into `out.txt`.

```
import csv

# r is textmode
# rb is binary mode
# binary mode is faster

with open('in.txt','rb') as tsvIn, open('out.txt', 'w') as tsvOut:
    tsvIn = csv.reader(tsvIn, delimiter='\t')
    tsvOut = csv.writer(tsvOut)

    for row in tsvIn:
        if "My String Value" in row:
            tsvOut.writerows(row)
```

My output looks like this.

```
D,r,a,m,a

1,9,6,1,-,0,4,-,1,3
H,y,u,n, ,M,o,k, ,Y,o,o
B,e,o,m,-,s,e,o,n, ,L,e,e
M,u,-,r,y,o,n,g, ,C,h,o,i,",", ,J,i,n, ,K,y,u, ,K,i,m,",", ,J,e,o,n,g,-,s,u,k, ,M,o,o,n,",", ,A,e,-,j,a, ,S,e,o

A, ,p,u,b,l,i,c, ,a,c,c,o,u,n,t,a,n,t,',s, ,s,a,l,a,r,y, ,i,s, ,f,a,r, ,t,o,o, ,s,m,a,l,l, ,f,o,r, ,h,i,m, ,t,o, ,e,v,e,n, ,g,e,t, ,a, ,c,a,v,i,t,y, ,f,i,x,e,d,",", ,l,e,t, ,a,l,o,n,e, ,s,u,p,p,o,r,t, ,h,i,s, ,f,a,m,i,l,y,., ,H,o,w,e,v,e,r,",", ,h,e, ,m,u,s,t, ,s,o,m,e,h,o,w, ,p,r,o,v,i,d,e, ,f,o,r, ,h,i,s, ,s,e,n,i,l,e,",", ,s,h,e,l,l,-,s,h,o,c,k,e,d, ,m,o,t,h,e,r,",", ,h,i,s, ,.,.,.

K,o,r,e,a,n,",", ,E,n,g,l,i,s,h

S,o,u,t,h, ,K,o,r,e,a
```

It should look like this with tab separated values

```
Drama     Hyn Mok Yoo     A public accountant's salary is far to small for him...etc
```

Comment: change `open('out.txt', 'rb')` to `open('out.txt', 'w')`

Comment: Awesome. I have an output now. But the cell values are aligned vertically rather than horizontally as in the original file. Additionally, the the individual characters in the cell values are separated by tabs. I was expecting the cell values to be aligned horizontally and separated by tabs.

Comment: To write a single row, use `writerow()`, not `writerows()`.  And if you want tabs as delimiter in the output file, you need to specify that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. Let's look at this line by line..

```
import csv
```

Import module `csv`. Ok.

```
with open('in.txt','rb') as tsvIn, open('out.txt', 'w') as tsvOut:
```

With auto-closed binary file read handle `tsvIn` from `in.txt`, and text write handle `tsvOut` from `out.txt`, do... (Note: you probably want to use mode `wb` instead of mode `w`; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250021/279627))

```
    tsvIn = csv.reader(tsvIn, delimiter='\t')
```

Let `tsvIn` be the result of the call of function `reader` in module `csv` with arguments `tsvIn` and `delimiter='\t'`. Ok.

```
    tsvOut = csv.writer(tsvOut)
```

Let `tsvOut` be the result of the call of function `writer` in module `csv` with argument `tsvOut`. You proably want to add another argument, `delimiter='\t'`, too.

```
    for row in tsvIn:
```

For each element in `tsvIn` as `row`, do...

```
        if "My String Value" in row:
```

If string `"My String Value"` is present in `row`. You mentioned that you wanted to show only those rows whose sixth element was equal to the string, thus you should use something like this instead...

```
        if len(row) >= 6 and row[5] == "My String Value":
```

This means: If the length of `row` is at least `6`, and the sixth element of `row` is equal to `"My String Value"`, do...

```
            tsvOut.writerows(row)
```

Call method `writerows` of object `tsvOut` with argument `row`. Remember that in Python, a string is just a sequence of characters, and a character is a single-element string. Thus, a character *is* a sequence. Then, we have that `row` is, according to the docs, a list of strings, each representing a column of the row. Thus, a row is a list of strings. Then, we have the `writerows` method, that expects a list of rows, that is, a list of lists of strings, that is, a list of lists of sequences of characters. It happens that you can interpret each of `row`'s elements as a row, when it's actually a string, and each element of that string as a string (as characters are strings!). All of this means is that you'll get a messy, character-by-character output. You should try this instead...

```
            tsvOut.writerow(row)
```

Method `writerow` expects a single row as an argument, not a list of rows, thus this will yield the expected result.

Comment: How do I insert the header row before the for loop?

Comment: Got it:  `row1 = next(tsvIn)` and  
    `tsvOut.writerow(row1)`

Comment: You definitely want to use `'rb'` and `'wb`' for the CSV module (see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4250021/279627)).  This has nothing to do with what is faster, it's rather a question of what works on all platforms.  Also note that a string isn't a "list" of characters.  It's a _sequence_ of characters, which is something less specific in Python terminology.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Thanks for noticing that, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import csv

# r is textmode
# rb is binary mode
# binary mode is faster

with open('in.txt','r') as tsvIn, open('out.txt', 'w') as tsvOut:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvIn, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(tsvOutm, delimiter='\t')

    [writer.writerow(row) for row in reader if "My String Value" in row]
```